# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' has occured

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

I'm trying to store images on my ASP.NET web forms website, in an 'Images' folder.

Here is the code behind my submit button:

```
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Get Filename from fileupload control
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(fileuploadimages.PostedFile.FileName);
    //Save images into Images folder
    fileuploadimages.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Images/" + filename));
    //Getting dbconnection from web.config connectionstring
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BallinoraDBConnectionString1"].ToString());
    //Open the database connection
    con.Open();
    //Query to insert images path and name into database
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Group_Images(ImageName,ImagePath) values(@ImageName,@ImagePath)", con);
    //Passing parameters to query
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageName", filename);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImagePath", "Images/" + filename);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    //Close dbconnection
    con.Close();
    Response.Redirect("~/Admin.aspx");
}
```

[SQL Server table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOdwP.png)

[Here is the error message I'm receiving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zqh6O.png)

Comment: The Table Structure didn't make it into the post. Can you add it? Thanks :)

Comment: Try reading the error message.

Comment: @scsimon Forgot to add the link! thanks.

Comment: Your column, `ID`, isn't NULLABLE so you must pass in a value when inserting, or make that column NULLABLE.

Comment: You just need to set your ID field as identity

Comment: @Hackerman Ah yes, works now, Thanks! :)

Comment: I am glad to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update the column `ID` in your database, set it as Identity Increment

[image: Identity Increment]